# Boost geometry polygon inner representation as a STL list?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-geometry

As far as I know, boost polygon is represented as a STL vector. This is not convenient for when a new point needs to be added at a specific index of the polygon, as this is linear complexity.

Is there a way how to make boost use a list representation or otherwise solve the problem of adding a point to an index of the polygon in constant time?

Comment: Are your polygons huge? If less than 1000 points I would ignore this vector problem, because list insert/erase typically requires memory (de)allocation, which is unbelievably slow.

Comment: @SvenNilsson makes an excellent point, always profile your code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The whole point of [the Boost Geometry *Design Rationale*](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/libs/geometry/doc/html/geometry/design.html) is to program to [*concepts*](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/libs/geometry/doc/html/geometry/reference/concepts.html), not [*models*](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/libs/geometry/doc/html/geometry/reference/models.html).

The default *model* of a polygon you describe indeed uses `std::vector`, but you can use any model - including your own types or third party types, given [some adaption](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/libs/geometry/doc/html/geometry/examples/example__adapting_a_legacy_geometry_object_model.html).

So, without further ado, use the [builtin model](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/libs/geometry/doc/html/geometry/reference/models/model_polygon.html) with a list:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c665d2c47550343f)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/geometry.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/point_xy.hpp>
#include <list>

int main() {
    using namespace boost::geometry;
    using Point = model::d2::point_xy<double>;
    model::polygon<Point, true, true, std::list> p;
}
```